# compare strings containing formatted data

Tags: c++, string

I am working on this project where I have strings that contain dates in the following format: str1-> "01/17/17" str2->"12/29/16".
I am not allowed to use any of the converting functions such as atoi or stoi.
I am looking at each character of the strings and compare them to see which is less. I set a Boolean array to true if month of str1 is <= to str2. I am clearly wrong. I cannot think of simple solution to this that does not involve converting to different data type, but I am not allowed to do so. I appreciate greatly anyone who would help.
Here is my code:

```
sortData(items);
bool date[5];
date[0] = false;        //month
date[1] = true;         // '/'
date[2] = false;        //day
date[3] = true;         // '/'
date[4] = false;        //year
//looking for smallest string
string str1;
string str2;
for (int i = 4; i < 7; i++)
{
    str1 = items[i].date;
    str2 = items[i + 1].date;
    int size = str1.length();
    int count = 0;
    while (count < size)
    {
        if (str1[count] <= str2[count] || str1[count + 1] <= str2[count + 1])
        {
            date[0] = true;

        }
        //0,1  

        count=count+3;          //3,4
        if (str1[count] <= str2[count] || str1[count + 1] <= str2[count + 1])
            date[2] = true;     //day
        count = count + 3;
                //6,7
        if (str1[count] <= str2[count] || str1[count + 1] <= str2[count + 1])
            date[4] = true;
        count=count+1;

    }

}
int m = 0;      //for debugging
```

Comment: No input/output example and no error? Well char '0' is less than char '1', and so on, because there are only day, month and year, it's nonsense to do a while, just a compare with priority (year -> month -> day)

Answer (score 1):

If you reorganize the string to yy/mm/dd you can use string comparison to find which one is less than or greater  than or equal to the other.  Assuming the strings are always in a 2 digit format, something like this should work:

```
//This assumes mm/dd/yy
string FixString(string input)
{
    return input.substr(6) + "/" + input.substr(0, 5);
}
int main()
{
    string test = FixString("01/17/17");
    string test2 = FixString("12/29/16");
    bool test3 = test < test2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a solution example with 2 string dates, it will compare the year, then month, and finally day, because of priority (year > month > day), after finding the first, it will stop and print the smallest.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1 = "01/17/17";
    string str2 = "12/29/16";
    string smallest;

    for(int i=7; i >=0 ; i-=3)
    {
        if(str1[i-1] < str2[i-1])
        {
            smallest = str1;
            break;
        }
        else if(str1[i-1] > str2[i-1])
        {
            smallest = str2;
            break;
        }
        if(str1[i] < str2[i])
        {
            smallest = str1;
            break;
        }
        else if(str1[i] > str2[i])
        {
            smallest = str2;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << smallest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```